# How to scroll a NestedScrollView while fading in a child view - smoothly?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a `NestedScrollView` that contains various children, one of which is a `ViewPager`.

I currently have it so that when a button is clicked, the `ViewPager` fades in and ***then*** the `NestedScrollView` scrolls up (so the `ViewPager` is at the top of the screen).

It works very nice and smoothly, but I want to *combine* the fading and scrolling into a single, concurrent animation.

This is the code I have used but, with this approach, neither the fading or the scrolling is smooth:

```
ObjectAnimator yTranslate = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(nestedScrollView, "scrollY", 450); // 450 is a temporary value, just for testing
ObjectAnimator alphaTranslate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewPager, "alpha", 1f); // Fade in the ViewPager
AnimatorSet animators = new AnimatorSet();
animators.setDuration(1000);
animators.playTogether(yTranslate, alphaTranslate);
animators.start();
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Android/Java.